# Trouble upgrading kernel on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I am trying to upgrade one of my 14.04 systems and I am getting the following error when running apt-get upgrade:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-111-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-111-generic but it is not installable
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-111-generic but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Here is my current setup:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l


$ uname -r
3.13.0-109-generic

$ ls /boot
abi-3.13.0-108-generic     initrd.img-3.13.0-108-generic  System.map-3.13.0-109-generic
abi-3.13.0-109-generic     initrd.img-3.13.0-109-generic  System.map-3.13.0-110-generic
abi-3.13.0-110-generic     lost+found                     vmlinuz-3.13.0-108-generic
config-3.13.0-108-generic  memtest86+.bin                 vmlinuz-3.13.0-109-generic
config-3.13.0-109-generic  memtest86+.elf                 vmlinuz-3.13.0-110-generic
config-3.13.0-110-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                       System.map-3.13.0-108-generic
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am just trying to upgrade to the most recent version of the 14 release.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested already,  `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Answer (score 0):

run into terminal

```
apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what happened, I first took a snapshot of the VM.  I attempted the upgrade with a -f flag and then rebooted.  On boot I had a kernel panic and it failed to boot.  I then restored to the snapshot.  I then removed all kernels except the current running kernel (109) as well as 108 for a backup.  I then did a reboot.  Once rebooted I did an up-get update, then apt-get upgrade.  It failed dependency again, I then added the -f flag and the install completed successfully.  I rebooted and was then running on the 119 kernel.  Did an update and upgrade again, system informed me of packages no longer in use and asked me to do an autoremove. I did this in a full cycle 3 times and everything got cleaned up.  System running great with no more updates.  Thanks for the help!